# How to relocate Moment variables to state from render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, state

I'd like to know how I can better store the variables I am using for moment in my react component.

I've already tried just declaring the variables in the constructor below the `setState`, but these variables are not changeable. I then tried to store the variables in the state, as key value pairs but since one of the values is dependent on another, it did not work.

Here is my current constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  scooter: props.scooter,
  header: props.header,
  reservation: ""
};
}


componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
this.setState({
  scooter: nextProps.scooter,
  header: nextProps.header
});
}
```

Some items will have to be called as well in `componentsWillRecieveProps` as the item will change with next props.

variables below

```
render() {
const reservation = this.state.scooter.state.LastAdminReservation;
var a = moment();
const c = moment(reservation.PendingDate);
const d = moment(reservation.EndDate);
const duration = d.from(c, true);
var timeSince = a.from(d, true);
const date = moment(reservation.DownloadAckDate).format("DD.MM.YYYY 
HH:mm");
```

I'd like to be able to call these variables in my return and have `var a` and `var timeSince` be updated on next props while not storing them in my render as this is bad practice. Thanks!

Comment: If you don't want them in your render and don't want them in state then your other option is to store them on the class like `this.timeSince = a.from(d,true)` then you can set them inside `componentWillReceiveProps` and inside your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this (putting in the state only variable that will be used inside other methods.

```
constructor() {
    super();

    const a = moment();
    const c = moment(new Date());
    const d = moment(new Date());
    const duration = d.from(c, true);
    const timeSince = a.from(d, true);

    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      timeSince
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try your best [not to derive state from props](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html). However, if you really need to, [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) is a safer method introduced in React 16.

`componentWillReceiveProps` is a deprecated method that you should be avoiding.

Instead, you can create a function that will return the date you need, and call it from your `render` method. If you are worried with performance, you can [memoize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) that function. [Example here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#what-about-memoization)

If you are using a state management solution like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/), you can also move that logic up to a selector and pass down only the data you need into your component.